# Where to find HuggingFace tokenize documentation

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface

Let's say I initialize a tokenizer like this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
```

I want to see the full documentation for this tokenizer, specifically the arguments I can use when calling this:

```
context_length = 128
tokenizer(
        element["content"],
        truncation=True,
        max_length=context_length,
        return_overflowing_tokens=True,
        return_length=True,
    )
```

I can see it using help(tokenizer), but would prefer to view it in a browser.

Seems like [this](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.3.3/model_doc/gpt2.html#transformers.GPT2TokenizerFast.save_vocabulary) is a version, but it's outdated.  The link to the latest version there points to a tutorial-like page.

Where is the definitive documentation for functions like this one and others (i.e. would like to see the analogous documentation for a datasets.dataset_dict.DatasetDict object)